# Cannot rebase on local repo, noop

Tags: git

I have a local only git, no remote. Simply a brand new git with a couple of commits (I'm just trying out stuff, specifically rebase):

- 291998a (HEAD, master) change 3
- 11d4a2f line 2
- 4e16089 line 1

When I run:

```
git rebase master -i HEAD~2
```

All I get is:
'there is no tracking information for the current branch'

What I did was I started the git rebase process, then I realised I did it wrong so did a rebase --abort. It said I had aborted and 'git status' says on branch master, nothing to commit, working tree clean.

But now when I try git rebase -i it says 'there is no tracking information for the current branch'

[edit] the problem is when I do git branch I get this. No idea why it did this.

```
* (no branch)
  master
```

Comment: It's not clear how you got into detached HEAD mode, but indeed, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Performing a 'git branch' showed:

```
* (no branch)
   master
```

I have no idea what switched it to this, all I did previously was create a new repo and abort out of a first rebase and checked it was  aborted...

Answer (score 0):

You are already on `master` so `git rebase master` gives `noop`. The correct command is

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

Comment: I tried that first but it simply says I have no upstream, so I changed to 'master' thinking it wanted a branch as other stackoverflow articles told people to put origin/master in the command. I am just trying to play with rebase on my local only git repo.

Comment: *"it simply says I have no upstream*" That very strange. `git rebase -i HEAD~2` doesn't require any upstream.

Comment: So, what I did was start the git rebase, then I realised I did it wrong so did a rebase --abort. It said I had aborted and git status says on branch master, nothing to commit, working tree clean. But when I try git rebase -i it says 'there is no tracking information for the current branch'

Comment: I did a git reset --hard to before I started the rebase and it's fine now. Why would it give me this error when it thinks everything is ok?

Comment: I found the reason, just not why :)
git is sitting on a '(no branch)' branch. Switching back to master made it work, even though I checked and it said I was not in the middle of a rebase after doing an initial abort.